# Workflow format exception

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow set to run when a list item is created such that when an item is added, 5 documents are created in a document library. I also add another row item to a list. The workflow gets suspended with the following error:

```
    RequestorId: 275cb289-d713-faa6-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) at Microsoft.Activities.Expressions.ParseNumber`1.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation) Exception from activity ParseNumber<Int32> Cast<Int32,Object> BuildDictionary<String,Object> Subroutine<Guid> Stage 1 Sequence Flowchart Sequence AddProjectNameToProjectParam.WorkflowXaml_3622b40b_5f49_4578_8456_52799a5f4111
```

Here is the workflow:
[image]

edit: The error went away when I changed The projectName column to be given the projectName workflow variable as "User ID(As integer)" Instead of just "as integer"... While this got rid of the format exception, this now doesn't set the projectName field to anything
[image]

edit 2: Further testing shows I can't replace the Variable:projectName with currentItem:project name.... I think the issue may be that the projectName column is a lookup. If that is indeed the issue, how can i work around this?

Comment: How are you setting the ProjName variable above?  What field is it using?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out, projectName was a lookup column, which doesn't take string data, it takes an integer- being the ID of the item in the lookup column. So, I set projectName to

```
CurrentItem:ID
```